# Strange cross browser Issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firefox, web, cross-browser

We have created a website [www.yutilaw.com](http://www.yutilaw.com) . Now this website is working fine in Chrome but in Firefox the website looks entirely different. the header is not visible.

Any suggestions how to solve this. I have no Idea where the problem is.

Wordpress version is  3.5.1

[image: Chrome shot, working fine]

[image: Firefox shot,Missing upper part]

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yutilaw.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: @Quentin Agree with you that it's not fit to Q&A format. i'll close it. thanks for your reponse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you have `margin-top: -500px;` for `#main` selector.

I'm not sure why you have that but try to remove / comment it out.

Comment: commenting that is making the "About" and "Clock" to shift down

Comment: Great! it work. Just remove the margin from their and added to individual elements. Thanks.